# How to do form handling in Django Generic CBV?

Tags: django

I'm trying to do the same thing below in Django Generic CBV.

**Function Based View**

```
def form_handling(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = SimilarStore(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('...')   
    else:
        form = SimilarStore()
    ...
```

**Class Based View**

```
class SimilarStoreCreateView(CreateView):
    model = SimilarStore
    form_class = SimilarStoreForm
    template_name='cms/similarstore_new.html'
    success_url=reverse_lazy('cms:similarstore')

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form = SimilarStoreForm(self.request.POST, self.request.FILES)
        form.save()
        return redirect(self.get_success_url())

    def form_invalid(self, form):
        form = SimilarStoreForm()
    ...
```

I'm confused about how I can check if `request.method` is POST or GET in Django Generic CBV. I know Django regular CBV supports `get()` and `post()`. However, in Generic views, there's no `post()`. What should I do to handle POST requests in Django Generic?

Also, my CBV codes throw an error `'SimilarStoreForm' object has no attribute 'cleaned_data'`. Why is that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CreateView` has `post()` method it's inherited from `ProcessFormView`. You can find method source [here](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/views/generic/edit.py#L129). As for your question from the source code you may see that `form_valid` and `form_invalid` method will be triggered only for `POST` requests.

You don't need to override `form_invalid` method since by default it will render invalid form with form's error. And you don't need to override `form_valid` also, `CreateView` do redirect automatically after. So you can simple do:

```
class SimilarStoreCreateView(CreateView):
    model = SimilarStore
    form_class = SimilarStoreForm
    template_name='cms/similarstore_new.html'
    success_url=reverse_lazy('cms:similarstore')
```

And this will give you same logic as in your function based view.

Answer (score 1):

CreateViews have a post method as shown below that you can use

```
def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    self.object = None
    return super().post(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

[Here is a good reference for all the methods and attributes of CBVs](https://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/2.0/django.views.generic.edit/CreateView/)

Answer (score 1):

Basically, your current setup is all you need. You see, `CreateView`'s `post` method is effectively its base class'es (`BaseCreateView`) `post` method which calls its own base class'es (`ProcessFormView`) `post` method, that being

```
class ProcessFormView(View):
    # ...
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        """
        Handles POST requests, instantiating a form instance with the passed
        POST variables and then checked for validity.
        """
        form = self.get_form()
        if form.is_valid():
            return self.form_valid(form)
        else:
            return self.form_invalid(form)
```

Therefore, whenever a POST HTTP request gets routed to `SimilarStoreCreateView` it will finally be `dispatch`ed to the aforementioned `post` method already implementing the desired workflow of yours.